# How to replace a period within string and not in Numeric using singlestore (MemSQL) DB REGEXP_REPLACE function

Tags: regex, regexp-replace, singlestore

I have a scenario wherein I want to replace a period when its surrounded by Alphabets and not when surrounded by Numbers. I figured out a Regular Expression pattern that can identify only the periods in Key names but the pattern is not working in SQL

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Amount.fee:0.75,Amount.tot:645.55","(?<!\d)(\.)(?!\d)","_","ig");
```

Expected output: Amount_fee:0.75,Amount_tot:645.55

Note, I am trying this because, In MemSQL I couldn't access JSON key when it has period in it.

Also verified the pattern "(?<!\d)(.)(?!\d)" using https://coding.tools/regex-replace and it working fine. But, SQL is not working. Am using MemSQL 7.1.9 and POSIX Enhanced Regular expression are supposed to be work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you are trying to workaround accessing a JSON key with a period, I will show you how to do that.

This can be done by either surrounding the json key name with backtics while using the shorthand json extract syntax:

```
select col::%`Amount.fee` from (select '{"Amount.fee":0.75,"Amount.tot":645.55}' col);
+--------------------+
| col::%`Amount.fee` |
+--------------------+
|               0.75 |
+--------------------+
```

or by using the json_extract_ builtins directly:

```
select json_extract_double('{"Amount.fee":0.75,"Amount.tot":645.55}', 'Amount.fee');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_extract_double('{"Amount.fee":0.75,"Amount.tot":645.55}', 'Amount.fee') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                         0.75 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to target dots that are in between two non digit characters, where the dot is *not* the first or last character in the string, you may match on `([^\d])\.([^\d])` and replace with `\1_\2`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Amount.fee:0.75,Amount.tot:645.55", "([^\d])\.([^\d])", "\1_\2", "ig");
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVt9mb/1) showing that the replacement is working.  Note that you might have to use `$1_$2` instead of `\1_\2` as the replacement, depending on the regex flavor of your SQL tool.

Comment: Didn't work in MemSQL, 1. SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Amount.fee:0.75,Amount.tot:645.55", "([^\d])\\.([^\d])", "\1_\2", "ig"); returned "Amoun1_2ee:1_25,Amoun1_2ot:641_25" 2. SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Amount.fee:0.75,Amount.tot:645.55", "([^\d])\\.([^\d])", "$1_$2", "ig"); returned Amoun$1_$2ee:$1_$25,Amoun$1_$2ot:64$1_$25

Comment: @ekko Sorry...my replacement was wrong, I had copied from your question.  Check the updated version which should be working now.

Comment: Didn't work again

Comment: My answer is working from Postgres as well as from a regex demo tool.  I don't have your database in front of me, and so I cannot test any more than I already have done here.